# React Native - Array Objects to AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, asynchronous

Just a quick question, I keep trying to make a list of item with AsyncStorage but I just can't figure it out. I use to try some attempts base on some blogs on the net but it's not working. So, I run here into SO hoping someone can help me.

Here is my code:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        myKey: []
    }
  }

  async getKey() {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key');
      this.setState({myKey: value});
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error retrieving data" + error);
    }
  }

  async saveKey(value) {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('@MySuperStore:key', value);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error saving data" + error);
    }
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

[Warning_ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8xo3.png)

```
    <TextInput
      style={styles.formInput}
      placeholder="Enter key you want to save!"  // This is the component where I think the warning came from. 
      value={this.state.myKey}
      onChangeText={(value) => this.saveKey(value)}
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the value you get from calling `AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key')` an object or an array? If it's just a single object, it looks like you probably want to append it to your `myKey` array.

```
async getKey() {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key');
    const myKey = [ ...this.state.myKey, value ];
    this.setState({ myKey });
    } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error retrieving data" + error);
  }
}
```

Comment: At first sir, it's just a single object that when I try to type second object... this second object will replace the first one. But with your code it, some how there's just an warning. I'll update the details in my question.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? You have an input, and when a user enters something here, you want to add that single character (since it updated on every change, right?) in you `myKey` array?